# ('float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer) problem is there another built-in function I could possibly use instead of linspace for plotting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

The problem lies here as i would like to plot the points from -0.4 to 0.8 in increments of 0.01 as there is an important part of the graph that im missing which happens after x = 0.6

```
x = np.linspace(-0.4,1,0.01)
y = np.sqrt(((47.9-72*x)/5))

plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
plt.plot(x,y,label = "k", linestyle = "-", color = 'Blue')

plt.xlabel("delta ($\Delta$) [m]")
plt.ylabel("Vc [m/s] ") #Velocity after it passes point C 
plt.title("TITLE")
plt.xlim([-0.4, 1])
plt.ylim([0,4.0])
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: `np.arange`. `linspace` uses the number of samples to generate, not the step size

Comment: You should show the `traceback`; we can guess the problem was in your `linspace` call, but you should make that clear.  Also, did you bother to reread the `linspace` docs?  From  that the problem should have been obvious.  The following `plt` calls aren't relevant if you can't get past the `linspace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use arange: `np.arange(-.4,.8,.01)`.

Comment: With range i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen stated, `np.linspace(...)` does not take float values, it takes an integer to represent the number of points between `start` and `stop`. You can not have half of a slice, so non-integers will throw an error, see more in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html).

As far as your problem, you are probably looking for something like `np.arange(...)` which generates an array between `stop` and `start` with a certain stepsize between points that doesn't have to be an integer, Learn more in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

For an example, let's use your code with `np.arange` instead:

We load the packages

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then build the data

```
x_array = np.arange(-0.4,1,0.01)
y_array = np.sqrt(((47.9-72*x_array)/5))
```

Finally we plot

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
plt.plot(x_array,y_array,label = "k", linestyle = "-", color = 'Blue')

plt.xlabel("delta ($\Delta$) [m]")
plt.ylabel("Vc [m/s] ") #Velocity after it passes point C 
plt.title("TITLE")
plt.xlim([-0.4, 1])
plt.ylim([0,4.0])
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Which yields:

[image: Your plot]